# Error during syscall FUTEX_WAIT Bad file descriptor why?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-emulator, qemu

I tried porting the Android emulator to the arm server. After some porting, qemu-system-aarch64 has been successfully compiled. However, an error occurred while running the Bad file descriptor. The code that was debugged through gdb is located at /emu-2.3-release/external/qemu/util /qemu-thread-posix.c:313

```
#ifdef __linux__
#define futex(...)              syscall(__NR_futex, __VA_ARGS__)
...
static inline void futex_wait(QemuEvent *ev, unsigned val)
{
    while (futex(ev, FUTEX_WAIT, (int) val, NULL, NULL, 0)) {
        switch (errno) {
        case EWOULDBLOCK:
            return;
        case EINTR:
            break; /* get out of switch and retry */
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "error: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why this error occurs and it is not mentioned on the web.

Help me,Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a solution but just ran into the same problem. Were you able to solve it in the meantime?

Comment: I have n’t solved it till now

Comment: I worked around it in qemu-thread-posix.c by using the phtread mutex stuff starting around line 351 instead of including futex.h in line 349.
But further down the line after the emulator loading UI appears I run into another futex blocking issue.